# How to clear contents of table completely?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pressing **del** simply doesn't do it. How can I clear contents of a cell or table **completely** ?

**Edit:** I thought it was pretty obvious by the question title and image, but what I want to do is empty the contents of the table, not delete the table. I want to also remove/clear the black coloring, but it simply won't go away. The coloring and the whole font and format of that colorful text below came from a *copy and paste* from my IDE in C++, CLion.

**Edit2:** I provided a working asnwer. Also note: I am on 2013 version.

[image: 1]

Comment: What do you mean by "clear completely"? `del` removes the content as expected.

Comment: All that is left is the formatting, so use the button, that clears the formatting or the button that wipes everything.

Comment: Clear formatting will only clear the text formatting, but will not touch the cell color and will not delete the text. @Ramhound, I cannot find a 'wipe' button.  Could you elaborate on where this button is please?

Comment: @DavidPostill I mean clearing that overly suspicious black entity which is drawn inside my *empty* table.

Comment: @rencjam Found the button and answered my question

Comment: I don't have a copy of office 2013 to take a picture of, there are two icons that exist, one removed all font changes to text, the other clears all formatting to anything highlighted

Comment: [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tycaX.png) explains all the relevant buttons and explains how to removed the highlight in your original screenshot.

Comment: @rencjam - there isn't a literal "wipe" button, but the icon is an eraser, and I was to lazy to look up what the icon called itself.  I was making a distinction between clearing the style of text and clearing all other formatting that might exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to select the table and click the `Clear All Formatting` button

[image: 1]

Comment: What version of word are you using? 2013?  I'll have to look for the 'Clear all formatting' button on 2010.  I'm sure iit exists, I just haven't located it yet.  Thanks

Comment: @rencjam Yes it is 2013.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely understanding your question as del does remove the contents.

If you're wanting to delete the table, click on the table, right click, delete table

[image]

If you're wanting to remove the cell color, highlight the whole table (or cells you want), right click, click on the paint bucket, choose No Color

[image]

Hope this helps you with your task.

Comment: `No color` didn't remove the black thing inside my *empty* table. This coloring is a product of copying and pasting text from my IDE in c++. I don't know how to clear the format so that the black color is gone.

Comment: That is because this author while correct suggested the wrong icon.  Your screenshot has "background" coloring not font coloring which is what the icon in this answer shows.